# Spotlight search with context?

Tags: macos, pdf, search, grep

I'd like to perform searches so that:

1) It can search in the text in a large number of pdf files. Specifically, I want to search within a directory with nested directories several layer deep, and they are mostly pdf files. There are about 50K files (roughly 10-50 pages each), so performance is crucial.

2) When it finds the result, it should return the matches plus context (think `grep -C 2`), instead of just the names of the files that contain the query.

I imagine this might be the easier with command line, but I don't mind using a program, if it's easier.
I don't need wild cards or regular expression capabilities, but it should support strings as a literal phrase ("does not").

[This script](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100320112701285) is kinda of similar to I need, but it uses grep to get the results and grep doesn't understand pdf (and I don't want to convert each pdf to text for each search).

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with OS X but on Linux I use [pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/manpage.html) and [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/). Both apps seem to be on macports.

Comment: @Glutanimate Thanks for the suggestions! I tried Recoll and it was quite helpful. (After indexing) The performance is pretty good, although I think Spotlight was still a bit faster. If you turn this to an answer I will check it.

Comment: Glad I could help! I posted an answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Linux user these are the two options that would come to my mind:

- [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) – powerful desktop search tool with a GUI and CLI. Shows search results in their context. Context verbosity is configurable (Options → GUI Options → Search parameters). Comparable to spotlight in that it requires indexing before performing a search.

  ➥ Use this for large document libraries
- [pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/manpage.html) – PDF equivalent to the CLI tool grep. Can also show results in their context. Context verbosity is also configurable (`--context <number of words>`). Works without prebuilding an index. Orders of magnitude slower than Recoll and Spotlight for larger document libraries.

  ➥ Use this for quick searches through smaller collections

Both are available through macports.